# Using $_GET variables in the URL?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, variables

I need to generate a simple error message on a page by passing a variable through the URL.

The URL is structured as follows:

http://site.com/parent-category/category/?error=pause

I'm sure it's the permalinks rewrite interfering, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: You need to know you to generate using $_GET variable, or how to add query args in url?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try adding the variable to the WordPress' array of 'recognised query variables'...

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_register_query_vars' );
function my_register_query_vars( $qvars ){
    //Add query variable to $qvars array
    $qvars[] = 'my_error';
    return $qvars;
}
```

Then the value of 'my_error' can be found via `get_query_var('my_error')`. (See [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var))

**EDIT**

From Otto's comment, it's better to do:

```
add_action('init','add_my_error');
function add_my_error() { 
    global $wp; 
    $wp->add_query_var('my_error'); 
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use that filter in particular. We have functions that you should use for that instead.


add_action('init','add_my_error');
function add_my_error() {
       global $wp;
       $wp->add_query_var('my_error');
}

Comment: Cool. It doesn't really matter, actually, I just prefer to not use deep hooks when shallow ones will do the job. :)

Comment: I always use `add_rewrite_tag($tagname,$regex)`. Any difference?

Answer (score 0):

This was the only way I could get this to work

```
add_action('init','add_query_args');
function add_query_args()
{ 
    add_query_arg( 'error', 'pause' );
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg