# Trying to put an array into 'post__in' => array() query not working

Tags: posts, query

Slight problem, I have the following code:

```
$purchaseprodid = $_GET['ids'];
$args = array(
                  'post_type' => 'prizes',
                  'post__in' => array($purchaseprodid)
                  );
                query_posts($args);

                while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

I am getting comma seperated numbers for id's in a url, and they dont seem to be querying the posts. If I manually type the id's in they work no problem, but just not when using a variable $purchaseprodid.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explode the string you obtain from `$_GET['ids']` into an array, at the moment you a parsing a to string `post__in` rather than an array of IDs.

Try

```
$purchaseprodid = isset($_GET['ids']) ? explode(',',$_GET['ids']) : array();
```

However, you can sometimes run into difficulties using `$_GET` with WordPress, it's better to use the API provided and register your variable, [see this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41370/using-get-variables-in-the-url/41373#41373).

Answer (score 1):

You can instead use the standard WordPress function `wp_parse_id_list` like this:

```
$purchaseprodid = isset( $_GET['ids'] ) ? wp_parse_id_list( $_GET['ids'] ) : array();
```

that checks that the input data is not already an array, clears duplicates and converts the type of each array element to integer.

More info at:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_id_list/