# How do I output a database option that is an array into a get_posts array?

Tags: php, get-posts, array, options

This must be fairly simple, but I'm puzzled. And I may be going about it backwards.

*How do I output a database option that is an array into a get_posts array?*

I have an option in the database that stores some post IDs in the array format `1234,5678' . I can retrieve and echo them with

```
$options = get_option( 'pu_theme_options' );
$newspostids = $options['pu_textbox'];
echo $newspostids;
```

so I know am getting the output `1234,5678'. The database "option" is just text, saved from a form field in theme options.

What I need to do is get the data from that option into a `get_posts` array so I can display the posts by ID.

What I need is for `get_posts` to function like this:

```
$news = get_posts( array( 
            'post_type' => 'post', 
            'post__in'=> array(1234,5678)
            ) );
```

And, obviously, this doesn't work, putting the variable directly into the array and expecting it to output `1234,5678' :

```
$news = get_posts( array( 
            'post_type' => 'post', 
            'post__in'=> array($newspostids)
            ) );
```

So how should this work?

Comment: Just check the type of the option. If array, put as is, if not then explode the commas (`explode(',', $option)`).. Can be confusing if you don't dump your data initially..

Comment: The database "option" is just text, saved from a form field in theme options. But it appears I do need to sanitize it.

Answer (score 1):

You could  use [`wp_parse_id_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_id_list/) to sanitize your comma seperated list of post IDs. It's defined as:

```
function wp_parse_id_list( $list ) {
    if ( !is_array($list) )
        $list = preg_split('/[\s,]+/', $list);

    return array_unique(array_map('absint', $list));
}
```

where we can see that it returns unique array values as well.

Note that [`absint()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/absint/) is defined in core as `abs( intval() )` and there's a  difference in the max output of [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) for 32 and 64 bit systems according to the PHP docs.

Comment: Ah, I think that's it; I'll try it. Similar: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43267/trying-to-put-an-array-into-post-in-array-query-not-working/

Comment: Using "include" as Gareth's answer works. Is there an advantage to using wp_parse_id_list ?

Comment: The `include` parameter is a wrapper for `post__in`, that uses  `wp_parse_id_list()`,  with an adjustment in `posts_per_page`.Yes that will work. You should validate the database output, e.g. to make sure it's not empty, because empty `post__in` or `include` will not make `get_posts()` return an empty array. Another thing to consider: Should we always trust the core to sanitize the user input data or should we take care of it ? The latter sounds more responsible ;-)  @markratledge

Answer (score 0):

get_posts doesn't have a post__in "variable", that's in wp_query, in get_posts (or get_pages) you would need to use include e.g.

```
$news  = get_posts(
 array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'include' => $newspostids,
 )
);
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts

Comment: But `get_posts()` is just a wrapper for `WP_Query()`, where  in fact `include` is translated into the `post__in` argument with  the help of `wp_parse_id_list()`.

Comment: oh right, I am just going on the codex and I would personally test that before anything else

Comment: Any argument that is valid for `WP_Query` can be passed to `get_posts`

Comment: This works; and I don't see any php errors in the logs.